# How can i access Context in _app.js file in nextjs in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

> Hello, I have a context provider file and _app.js file below. i want
>   access AppContext in _app.js file. can any one help me, how can i
>   access the AppContext in _app.js file.
>
> I have import context in _app.js file and check but i can not get
>   context in _app.js file. can any one help me to correct this code and
>   let me know whats the problems here.

### Context File

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const AppContext = createContext();
let timeout = null;

const baseURL = "api/v1/";
const headers = { 'Accept': 'application/json', "Content-type": "application/json" };

const AppContextProvider = (props) => {
const [account, setAccount] = useState();
const [alert, setAlert] = useState();

const AlertType = { success: "success", error: "error", info: "info", warning: "warning" }
const updateAccount = (objAccount) => {
    setAccount(objAccount);
}

const updateAlert = (objAlert) => {
    if (objAlert) {
        if (objAlert.type == AlertType.success) { objAlert = { message: objAlert.message, type: objAlert.type, cssClass: "alert-teal" }; }
        else if (objAlert.type == AlertType.error) { objAlert = { message: objAlert.message, type: objAlert.type, cssClass: "alert-danger" }; }
        else if (objAlert.type == AlertType.warning) { objAlert = { message: objAlert.message, type: objAlert.type, cssClass: "alert-warning" }; }
        else if (objAlert.type == AlertType.info) { objAlert = { message: objAlert.message, type: objAlert.type, cssClass: "alert-info" }; }
    }
    setAlert(objAlert);

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(() => { setAlert(); }, 8000);
}


const ExecuteAPI_Get = async (action) => {
    let url = baseURL + action;
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: headers
    }).catch(err => { console.log(err); });
    return await response.json();
}
const ExecuteAPI_Post = async (action, params) => {
    let cookie = getCookie('Bearer');
    if (cookie) { headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + cookie; }
    let url = baseURL + action;
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(params),
    }).catch(err => { console.log(err); });
    return await response.json();
}

//Cookies
const setCookie = (cname, cvalue, date) => {
    var expires;
    if (typeof date === "number") {
        let d = new Date(); d.setTime(d.getTime() + (parseInt(date) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
    }
    else { expires = "expires=" + date.toString(); }
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
const getCookie = (cname) => {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}



return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={{ account, updateAccount, alert, updateAlert, ExecuteAPI_Get, ExecuteAPI_Post, setCookie, getCookie }}>
        {props.children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
)
}


 export default AppContext;
 export { AppContextProvider }
```

> ### _app.js file

```
              import '../public/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css';
              import '../public/assets/css/common.css';
              import '../public/assets/css/style.css';

              import Router from 'next/router';
              import { AppContext, AppContextProvider } from '../components/contextprovider';
              import App from "next/app";
              import { PageTransition } from 'next-page-transitions';
              import Layout from '../components/layout/layout';

              //context not found
              export default class MyApp extends App {
              static contextType = AppContext;
              static async getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) {
                let pageProps = {}
                if (Component.getInitialProps) { pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx) }
                return { pageProps }
              }

            constructor(props, context) {
                super(props, context);
                Router.events.off('routeChangeStart', () => { }); Router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', () => { }); Router.events.off('routeChangeError', () => { });
                Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', (url) => { }); Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', (url) => { }); Router.events.on('routeChangeError', (url) => { });
            }
            componentDidMount() { this.CheckLogin(); }

            CheckLogin = () => {
                let cookie = this.getCookie("Bearer");
                if (cookie) {
                    //this.context.ExecuteAPI_Post('auth/me', {}).then((res) => {
                    //    console.log(res);
                    //    if (res && res.data) { this.context.updateAccount(res.data); }
                    //});

                    if ((Router.pathname == '/login' || Router.pathname == '/signup')) { Router.push('/'); }
                }
                else {
                    if (Router.pathname != '/signup') {
                        this.setCookie("Bearer", "", 0);
                        Router.push('/login');
                    }

                }
            }
            //Temporory after get context in _app.js then remove this code and get from context
            setCookie = (cname, cvalue, date) => {
                var expires;
                if (typeof date === "number") {
                    let d = new Date(); d.setTime(d.getTime() + (parseInt(date) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
                    expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
                }
                else { expires = "expires=" + date.toString(); }
                document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
            }
            getCookie = (cname) => {
                var name = cname + "=";
                var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                    var c = ca[i];
                    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                        c = c.substring(1);
                    }
                    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }

            render() {
                const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
                return (
                    <AppContextProvider>
                        <Layout>
                            <PageTransition timeout={300} classNames="page-transition-main page-transition">
                                <Component {...pageProps} />
                            </PageTransition>
                        </Layout>

                        <style jsx global>{`
                            .page-transition-main{width:100%}
                            .page-transition-enter {opacity: 0;}
                            .page-transition-enter-active {opacity: 1;}
                            .page-transition-exit {opacity: 1;}
                            .page-transition-exit-active {opacity: 0;transition: opacity 300ms;}
                      `}</style>
                    </AppContextProvider>
                );
            }
            }
```

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, I don't know where to put the provider. I need it to toggle my material-ui theme from light to dark.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the context value in the same place of a provider is placed. So you can separate in two files:

```js
// _app.tsx
import { ThemeProvider } from '../contexts/theme';
import Container from './_container';
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';

function MyApp(appProps: AppProps) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider>
      <Container {...appProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

```js
// _container.tsx

import type { AppProps } from 'next/app';
import { ThemeProvider as SCThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { defaultColors, useTheme } from '../contexts/theme';

const Container = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  const { colors } = useTheme();

  return (
    <>
      <SCThemeProvider theme={{ colors: colors ? colors : defaultColors }}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </SCThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default Container;
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this:

```
# File: app-context.ts
const AppContext = React.createContext({
  user: null,
  isAuthenticated: false,
  setUser: null,
});
export default AppContext;

# File: _app.tsx
import AppContext from "./app-context";
export default class MyApp extends App {

  render() {
     const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

     return (
        <AppContext.Provider 
           value={{
             user: "todo",
             isAuthenticated: false,
             setUser: "todo",
           }}
         >
           <Component {...pageProps} />
        </AppContext.Provider>
       );
    }
}
```